# Dynamic DNS and Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, dyndns

I am testing exchange 2010 in a test lab and would like to be able to send/receive email externally. Is there a dynamic dns service that allows adding of mx records? or another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's only like a bazillion of them. Try [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/).